# Java 8 Stream loses type information

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following stream to select objects that match a certain criteria:

```
    protected final Map<String, PropertyMapping> propertyMappings = new LinkedHashMap();

    public List<PropertyMapping> getPropertyMappingsByAnnotation(final Class annotation) {
        return propertyMappings.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(pm -> pm.getAnnotation(annotation) != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

The filter somehow causes the Stream to lose track of the generic type of the stream which causes the collect statement to fail with the following error:

```
incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.List<PropertyMapping>
```

If I change the filter to pm -> true for example the stream works again. What causes this behavior and is there a way to avoid this? It probably has something to do with the 'annotation' class that gets passed in. I tried to pass a final modifier to see if that fixes the problem.

This is the signature of the getAnnotation method:

```
public final <T extends Annotation> T getAnnotation(Class<T> annotationClass)
```

Comment: Can you include the declaration of "propertyMappings" variable including generics? I.e. Map<?, ?>.

Comment: If I understand correctly: `T extends Annotation` will not allow the `Class<T>` to be converted like you're trying to do. You're returning a subclass of `T` and there will be issues with this conversion when passing in the parent class `T`.

Comment: I can't see from your code why your filter should affect the return type at the end of the stream. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: I will try to make the example as complete as possible. What puzzles me is that the filter predicate somehow triggers this behavior as it only needs to return a boolean value afaik.

Comment: The key point is that the `getAnnotation` method of `PropertyMapping` is generic, which makes passing a raw `Class` to it an unchecked operation. Had that method a non-generic signature ala `Annotation getAnnotation(Class cl)`, it was not an unchecked operation und worked. However, the accepted answer, eliminating the raw type, is the correct solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The obvious issue I can see is that you are trying to pass a plain `Class` variable as an argument to a method that expects a `Class<T>` where `<T extends Annotation>`. I imagine that the compiler is failing to fully figure that method call out and it's causing the compilation error at the end of the stream chain. If you fix that, your mystery problem might go away.

Something like this:

```
public <T extends Annotation> List<PropertyMapping> 
    getPropertyMappingsByAnnotation(Class<T> annotation) {
```

Comment: Yes that fixes the problem in the most elegant way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, does collect here know what kind of list it needs to produce (ArrayList/LinkedList)? Try something like this:

```
List<PropertyMapping> result = propertyMappings.values().stream()
  .filter(pm -> pm.getAnnotation(annotation) != null)
  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

If this doesn't work then maybe try adding a wildcard to the Class argument, or even a type.